# error: incompatible types: Executor cannot be converted to Activity

Tags: android

I am developing an otp based login in which otp is not being fetched from firebase due to which sms is not received..  In my previous project I was receiving the otp in my phone but in this project it shows error executors cannot be converted to activity. previous code was the same

the code is attached below

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskExecutors;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText phn,otp;
    private Button btn11,btn12;
    private String verificationId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        phn = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        otp = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone2);


        btn11 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        //btn12 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);

        btn11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mphn = phn.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mphn)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter a valid phone number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    String phone = "+91" + phn.getText().toString();
                    sendVerificationCode(phone);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String phone) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phone,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
               (((((((((((((( TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,))))))))))))))))))))) //Error is in this line.(avoid the brackets. it's just to highlight. error is written in title)
                mCallbacks
        );
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            //Getting the code sent by SMS
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

            //sometime the code is not detected automatically
            //in this case the code will be null
            //so user has to manually enter the code
            if (code != null) {
                otp.setText(code);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            //storing the verification id that is sent to the user
            verificationId = s;
        }
    };

    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        //signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to remove the Error:

I referred firebase phone auth documentation and made the necessary changes:

Replace this:

> PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
> phoneNumber, //phone number to be verified
> 60, // validity of the OTP
> TimeUnit.SECONDS,
> (Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
> mCallBack // onVerificationStateChangedCallback
> );

With this

> PhoneAuthOptions options =
> PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
> .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
> .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
> .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
> .setCallbacks(mCallBack)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
> .build();
> PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

Also, add this to your app/gradle file dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
```

This will help firebase to open the browser for reCAPTCHA verification.

Comment: Hi, I am unable to read SmsCode in this replaced code, in the previous code it was working fine. Could you please help me read the verification code so I can verify the number?